# Add a filter bean to spring-security filter chain based on condition in applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We have a spring-security filter chain as below where we provide the list of filters for each url pattern in the applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy"> <constructor-arg index="0">
        <list>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/rest" filters="
                sessionContextIntegrationFilter,
                ${bean.loggingFilter},
                ${bean.basicProcessingFilter},`
```

Now, is there any way to add a filter to this chain based on a condition? Something similar to below using SpEL

```
"#{'${some.condition}'.equalsIgnoreCase('true') ? actualFilter: dummyFilter}" />
```

Without using annotations or profiles please suggest a solution which can be implemented in the same xml file.

Update: I have tried below code before posting this question and it did not work for me, but as per comments from @R.G looks like it should work. Please point me where it was wrong **(For simplicity I replaced the condition with 'true')**

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy"> <constructor-arg index="0">
<list>
    <security:filter-chain pattern="/rest" filters="
        sessionContextIntegrationFilter,
        ${bean.loggingFilter},
        ${bean.basicProcessingFilter},
        #{ 'true' == 'true' ? 'actualFilter' : 'dummyFilter' }"/>
</list></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: The updated code works as expected for me . For example `'false' == 'true'` gets the `dummyFilter` bean. Please update the complete code ( for example in github or so ) with the exact exception/error you are getting. There could be version mismatch between our codes and hence the difference in results

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It was failing for me because of a different error in the xml. Thankyou for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following would switch between filter beans based on condition

```
    <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy"> <constructor-arg index="0">
    <list>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/rest" filters="
            sessionContextIntegrationFilter,
            ${bean.loggingFilter},
            ${bean.basicProcessingFilter},
            #{ some.condition == 'true' ? 'actualFilter' : 'dummyFilter' }"/>
    </list></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Comment: are you sure this would work? I tried the same, and got error when I launch my tomcat that no bean found with id #{ true == 'true' ? 'actualFilter' : 'dummyFilter' }

Comment: Worked for me . Tested before sharing the code . If `some.condition` is evaluating to `boolean` then you don't need to check that with equality , just `#{some.condition ? 'actualFilter': 'dummyFilter'}` should work

Comment: Instead of using the condition, I tried by directly placing 'true' in the code. I did not get any error during server launch when I used ` #{ true ? 'actualFilter' : 'dummyFilter' }`  but I am getting an error when I use  ` #{ 'true' == 'true' ? 'actualFilter' : 'dummyFilter' }`. Can you please tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please update the question with the failing code